# c# reading all entries of the same value in dictionary/

Tags: c#, dictionary

new to c#.
I'm trying to make a simple system where I can search through a list of objects and when it belongs to a certain ID. Put it in a List/ArrayList so I can read it out/do anything else.

Each "item" has a locationID. When I enter this location and press "look". The program should check which location I'm in and take out only the "items" with the same ID.

In practise. The list of items is going to be quite big (and locations too). So it seems a waste of processing to go through the list again and again. That's why I thought of using a dictionary. But I don't seem to be able to access multiple entries in the dictionary, only at one specific place.

for example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> itemLoc = new Dictionary<string, int>();
itemLoc.Add("pen", 011);
itemLoc.Add("paper", 011);
itemLoc.Add("tv remote", 012);

//print everything in location 011
```

Sorry for a lack of code. I'm still figuring out how to get my head around this. I've been researching ArrayLists, Lists, Hashtables, and these Dictionaries. But with none I've been able to achieve what I'm looking for effectively.

I could do a foreach, and check each entry. But like mentioned above. That would seem a waste of processing.

Any idea's or tips?
A nudge in the right direction code-wise would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not sticking these in a DB and doing your query there - would seem a reasonable solution for this (and probably easier to maintain long term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information as to the constraints of your problem.  A `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` will perform faster, but you haven't identified if you can have multiple items in multiple locations (for example, can "paper" be in 011 and 012 or just in 011?)  In that case, every time you add you will have to make sure that item is not already in another location.

A very simplified approach would be to break it down very simplistically, and optimize based on your results.

```
class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyItem> myItems = new List<MyItem>()
        {
            new MyItem() { Location = "011", Name = "pen" },
            new MyItem() { Location = "011", Name = "paper" },
            new MyItem() { Location = "012", Name = "tv remote" }
        };

        var specificItems = myItems.Where(f => f.Location == "011");

        foreach (var item in specificItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Once you perform your benchmark, you can consider switching it to something (perhaps a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: Yes, each object can only be in one place at the same time. is this efficient/fast enough to do multiple times a minute when the number of locations will be 20+ and items are going to be over 400?

Comment: @TwanMul: That's pretty small.  It should be fast enough for your use in that case.  You can perform some basic benchmarking using the `Stopwatch` class.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is storing integer values at locations specified by the hashes of the string keys you are utilizing.

A better idea would be to use `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` (or whatever C# has for a list class), do something like `itemLoc.Add(011, new List<string>()); itemLoc.Get(011).Add("pen");` when you're adding the first item in a location (so you'd want to check if the location exists as a key in the dictionary first), and then just `itemLoc.Get(011).Add("paper");` afterwards.

Note that my syntax may not be correct as I haven't used C# myself, but it shouldn't be that different. And if the C# dictionary class has an `AddIfAbsent()`-type method, that would be useful to simplify the keychecking I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary, by definition, has one value for each key. You cannot access several values with a single key.

You can however, use a List as value. So, if you want to make a collection of items in the same location and reuse it later you can store it in a dictiory where key is locationID: Dictionary>

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary provides mapping *from* the key *to* the value, but not the other way around.  You could build another Dictionary that has the location Ids as key and a collection of items as the value and look up the location id that way

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary will either let you find the item based on the location efficiently, or the location based on the item efficiently, but not both. (That's not to say isn't horribly inefficient to do it the other way, just less so and generally O(n) rather than something faster.)

So, you have a couple possibilities. The simplest is simply to iterate over `itemLoc.Values` and look for what you want. More complex would be to maintain a second collection, a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`, which would store the whole list of items per location. This will make lookups very fast and easy at the cost of more work to maintain the data (inserts, updates, deletes).

It's all about what you want to optimize for. In the most extreme case, you could ditch the `Dictionary<string,int>` and use the `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` exclusively, searching that when you need to find the location for an item-- but you'd only want to do that if that type of lookup is very rare.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>>
```

This way you can add multiple items to each location

e.g.

```
var locItems = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

List<string> items = new List<string>() { "item1", "Item2", "item3" };

locItems.Add(1, items);

// Get all items from location 1 ...
List<string> items = locItems[1];

foreach(string s in items)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

// Now add another item to the list
items.Add("Some new item");

// Since this is by ref - the list in the dict will be modified 
// so you don't need to worry about re-adding it to the dict
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! one small noob question. `var locItems` : does var mean i can choose my own var, or is this how you write it? for the first, which var would you recommend.

Comment: var is just an implicitly type variable declaration - i.e. the usage infers the type. You could write string mystring = "bob", or you could write var mystring = "bob". Both of these equate to the same thing since assigning the value "bob" to the variable infers that the type of the variable is a string. You could change the line List<string> items = locItems[1]; to var items = locItems[1]; because the locItems[1] would return a List<string> and therefore the type of "items" would be inferred from the usage

Answer (score 0):

The way the code looks now, you'll only be allowed to have a single pen, paper, ect. This is because you are using them as the keys to the dictionary. A better way of accomplishing this task would be to have a

`Dictionary<int, List<string>>`

The int would be the room id (001, 011, ect) and the list would be the object stored in each room. Given the room id, you can now iterate through the list of all things stored in that room.